# Databricks-CLI - ValueError: Timeout value connect was Timeout

Tags: azure-databricks

I'm setting up secret scope within azure databricks and for that I've installed and configured Databricks-CLI. I'm able to configure databricks tokens.

But, whenever I execute any of the commands on Databricks CLI, I do get following error :

```
Error: ValueError: Timeout value connect was Timeout(connect=None, read=None, total=None), but it must be an int or float.
```

Is it anything to do with firewall or network ?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the command which you are trying along with the screenshot of the error message?

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT - edited the question with screenshot.  hope, this helps

Comment: Hi @Shankar I’m working with the product team and get back to you when I have more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, my terminal was not porting the proxy across. So have to export http and https proxy before connecting to CLI. This resolved the issue.

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/ 
export https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyhost:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/583797/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-terminal/584183#584183